# Verb in active voice for "being penetrated"

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

The context is sexual and the example, straightforward: providing an alternative to "a man's penis penetrates a woman's vagina" where the female organ is the subject of the sentence, and using a verb in active voice. The verb should not have major connotations of passivity, so "accept" cannot be... accepted.

The friend who came up with this question believes no such verb exist, pointing at stereotypical associations between genders and active/passive roles. I couldn't find a valid alternative, but neither of us is a native speaker.

I'm looking for a verb in common or formal language, so no slang!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63212/discussion-on-question-by-adulte-terrible-verb-in-active-voice-for-being-penetr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were erotic fiction, and I needed to express the ***assertive role*** of a  woman during lovemaking, I might say:

- she *tightly squeezed* his *turgid man-root* (etc.)
- her vaginal muscles *clenched*/*seized* his phallus (etc.)

Answer (score 5):

"**enveloped,enveloping,envelops**" Put her situation, feelings and wants first then the mans. Sit back and watch the dominance and social conditioning ensue.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/envelop

Answer (score 2):

"Took in" could work. And I've seen "swallowed" in racier contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually talking about that with some friends the other day. We thought it's a shame that most of these terms constrain the women's perspective to passivity. 
and we came up with the term "to circumclude". 
Imagine this in a erotic novella: her vagina circumcluded his penis.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has proposed "circlusion," which I think has a nice ring to it. http://www.maskmagazine.com/the-mommy-issue/sex/circlusion

Answer (score -4):

"..her vagina engorged the penis"

> Engorged: to swallow greedily

As in dictionary.com

This is as close as I can get to being active without using slang.
Hope it helped :)

Comment: that's putting the wrong thing in the the active role for this question.